# How to configure Linux Remote Kernel in V10?

Tags: remote-access

I have read couple of posts and it seems that Mathematica has changed some settings over the years. So I will make the title explicit, so it is clear I want to setup remote kernels in V10.

My local(home) laptop is connected to internet. The system is

```
Windows 7 X64  --  Mathematica X64 10.0.2
```

Every time I want to use the remote server, I first connect to VPN, the using putty, I can access the remote MMA

```
Linux  -- Mathematica X64 10.0.2
```

The remote MMA is installed in my personal folder, and only accessible to myself.
I have to launch it from

```
./home/XXX/myname/MMA
```

Then using `./math` to launch it.

Question, how do I setup remote kernel in this case?
Do I have to setup on both machines?

I am not quite sure about the IP (hostname:), is there a way to find it out on the remote machine? There is no place for me to enter my `username` and `password`, how do I set it up?

How fast of the internet do I have to have to ensure a good connection?

[image]